# Powershell command line parameter with single quote will break command line

Tags: powershell

I am invoking a powershell script from a batch file

```
powershell createshortcut.ps1 "%~n0"
```

However if the parameter has a single quote (expanded sample)

```
powershell createshortcut.ps1 "Divertirsi con l'ortografia"
```

the parser will throw an error

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Obviously the parameter's content is unknown.

Powershell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  2189
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell PowerShell that it will be processing a `-File` rather than a `-Command`.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File createshortcut.ps1 "Divertirsi con l'ortografia"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either escape it using a single backtick (`):

```
powershell createshortcut.ps1 "Divertirsi con l`'ortografia"
```

Or replace double-quotes by simple ones and use `''`:

```
powershell createshortcut.ps1 'Divertirsi con l''ortografia'
```

Comment: I don't know in advance what is the content of the parameter

Comment: You could perform the replacement in your batch script before piping it to PowerShell.